# Right Align contents of a Vertically Oriented StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I want to right-align the contents that are displayed in a vertically oriented `StackPanel`, I've tried `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` on the `StackPanel` itself and the control in the `ListBox's` `DataTemplete` (in this case a `TextBox`, but in reality I have a `UserControl` in the real app)

here is the current result... i want the right edge of each `TextBox` to be right-aligned...

[image: not right-aligned]

Here is the xaml, pretty simple...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:WpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance WpfApplication2:Model, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" BorderBrush="Black" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

and here is the model I'm using to test this out with...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class Model
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        static IDictionary<int, string> dict;

        public string[] Numbers
        {
            get { return dict.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray(); }
        }

        public Model()
        {
            if (dict != null) return;
            dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
                       {
                           {1, "one"}, 
                           {2, "two"},
                           {3, "three"},
                           {4, "four"},
                           {5, "five"},
                           {6, "six"},
                           {7, "seven"},
                           {8, "eight"},
                           {9, "nine"},
                           {10, "ten"},
                           {11, "eleven"},
                           {12, "twelve"},
                           {13, "thirteen"},
                           {14, "fourteen"},
                           {15, "fifteen"},
                           {16, "sixteen"},
                           {17, "seventeen"},
                           {18, "eighteen"},
                           {19, "nineteen"},
                           {20, "twenty"},
                           {30, "thirty"},
                           {40, "forty"},
                           {50, "fifty"},
                           {60, "sixty"},
                           {70, "seventy"},
                           {80, "eighty"},
                           {90, "ninety"},
                           {100, "one hundred"},
                           {200, "two hundred"},
                           {300, "three hundred"},
                           {400, "four hundred"},
                           {500, "five hundred"},
                           {600, "six hundred"},
                           {700, "seven hundred"},
                           {800, "eight hundred"},
                           {900, "nine hundred"},
                           {1000, "one thousand"},
                       };

            for (var number = 1; number <= 1000; number++)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(number)) continue;

                var divisor = number < 100 ? 10 : 100;
                var separator = divisor == 100 ? " and " : "-";

                var key = (number / divisor) * divisor;
                var mod = number % divisor;
                dict.Add(number, dict[key] + separator + dict[mod]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend that, the selection of the item will be dimished as the items do no longer span the full width (also if you do not need selection in the first place you should use an ItemsControl).

Comment: ahh ok, i see your updated answer, that makes more sense. thanks! btw you've been helping me with a lot of my wpf questions, thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) to set the [`HorizontalContentAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx) of the `ListBoxItems` to `Right`.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**Note:** This is different from setting the `HorizontalAlignment` in that the items will still span the whole `ListBox` which has an impact on item selection.

Answer (score 0):

Setting HorizontalAlignment on the stackpanel works for me.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: The items themselves will still be left-aligned within the panel.

Comment: H.B. is right, this was what I was originally trying to do, but it keeps the textbox's left aligned while right-aligning the stackpanel (basically only the widest textbox is right-aligned and all others are left-aligned to this textbox)